# Adding Custom Security to Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, api-key, swashbuckle

I'm new to using swagger as my UI to test and debug and show documentation of my web API projects.

In a recent project (type: ASP.NET Web API) i encountered a problem,
my API didn't have any kind of security as it's interface is not clear to anyone.
But i need to secure the swagger UI since everybody can access my full documentation by just adding a "Swagger" after the url of api !!

Since i added the swagger easily by out-of-the-box swashbulckle nuget-package i don't know how to add any kind of security to it. if any body could give a step by step walk-through i would really appreciate it.

One more thing is that i tried adding below line to `SwaggerConfig.cs` but it didn't enforce any special api-key and i can open swagger ui by simply entering someting like `http://localhost:4505/swagger` in my browser:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
     .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
        c.ApiKey("key-11111-0000-1111-test")
              .Description("API Key Authentication")
              .Name("apiKey")
              .In("header");

        c.EnableApiKeySupport("apiKey", "header");
        });
```

( please note that i omitted configurations that weren't relevant to question from above code block )

Do i need to apply the api-key security to api itself insted of swagger?if yes, please show a simple way to do it.

**Update #1 :**
I found a hack by just changing the address of swagger-ui.
just add this line to `SwaggerConfig.cs` :

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                   //a long list of auto generated stuff
                   //don't touch them if you don't know how to change them
                })
                   //next line is what you add
                  .EnableSwaggerUi("sandbox-passphrase-000000-passphrase2/swagger/{*assetPath}");
```

Then the access-link to Swagger-ui would be something like below:

http://your-api.com:port/sandbox-passphrase-000000-passphrase2/swagger/index

**But this is not what i want**, i need something like adding a username/password text box to swagger-ui to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: is your api secured in any way?

Comment: no as i said "my API doesn't have any kind of security as its interface is not clear to anyone", i just need to secure swagger-ui, api interface is hidden and it won't need security for now.

Comment: can you explain how should we add a custom index view to swagger ui and after that, how do we hide the documentations in it and then where we check the entered username and password, please?